# schtasks Как добавить в программу в подпапку schtasks

Tags: windows, schedule, scheduler

Как добавить через команду schtasks в cmd программу к примеру Test.exe 
В подпапку schtasks

[image: Вот подпапка schtasks]

Если кто то знает помогите

Comment: Это иерархическое представление имеющихся **задач** в оснастке планировщика. Нужно создать **задачу** или создать **задачу** так, чтобы она попала в одну из **категорий** при отображении планировщиком?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Да нужно сделать чтобы задача к примеру INCRYPTION попала к примеру в папку Microsoft и там дальше свой путь

Comment: Как я понял, для этого надо зарегистрировать свой COM-обработчик для использования интерфейса IComHandlerAction. Либо взять уже готовый обработчик, зарегистрированный в ОС. Могу только отправить к документации производителя [IComHandlerAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-icomhandleraction). Впрочем, можно и по тупому. Экспортируйте уже существующую задачу в XML. Отредактируйте её и импортируйте обратно. Значение тэга **<ClassId>** и определяет нужный интерфейс- зарегистрированный обработчик - проще говоря, тот раздел, куда попадет задание.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Можете отправить пример кода с C# - Java?

Comment: Если речь идет о примере для импорта задания с помощью c#, то ответ можно найти на SO:[add task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071276/)

Comment: @Daemon-5 Спасибо